# select the nearest preceding node called BName that DOES NOT have a grandparent called "test"?

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-2.0

How can I select the nearest preceding node called BName that DOES NOT have a parent of a parent called "Test" in Xpath 2.0?

That's how I'm testing if parent node is called "test" (thanks to @nwellnhof)

```
preceding::BName[not(parent::Test)][1]
```

Now I need to test one level up if the parent of the parent is "Test" as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write an `and` expression in the predicate: `preceding::BName[not(parent::Test) and not(../parent::Test)][1]`.